# get selected row value from Dynamic CRM main grid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Hi i want to fecth (column) values  of selected row from the main grid, on click of ribbon button .After getting value i want to copy that values but however in first place i m not able to get the value on button click.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll want to modify the Ribbon XML.

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309639.aspx and http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx